# Keeping two elements inline, allow overflow text to wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was trying to display two elements inline. First element is normal element and second one is an anchor tag. If the anchor tag text length exceeds the available space, I want it to wrap next line, preferably without breaking word in between.

But I am not able to achieve the inline-style when I tried break-word.

The anchor just moves to next line when the length of the text exceeds the current line. Example way I would like to display is:

> ||| Hello Mannnnnnnnnn |||
>
> ||| nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn |||

```css
.parent {
  // display : flex;
  //display : inline; 
}
.first {
  display: inline;
}
.second {
  display: inline;
  max-width: fill-available;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="first">
    Hello
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <a href="#">ManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManMan</a>
  </div>
</div>`
```

Following codepen has the code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqrJmo

I was trying to do flexbox style but that's worse. Following codepen has `display:flex`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRKPQr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.) Don't use `DIV` s, but `span` s (which are inline by default).

2.) Just put it all into one DIV without any special settings (could also just be a `p` tag) - I erased a lot from the original code

3.) Make the space between the first word and the second - long - word a `&nbsp;` (non breaking space)

4.) Since you probably don't want subsequent words in the same container to break, wrap the first word and the link with a `<span>` tag to which you assign the `word-wrap: break-word;` instead of the whole container/DIV.

5.) for the rest, see my snippet

```css
.x {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="x">Hello&nbsp;<a href="#">ManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManMan</a>
  </span> and some more bla bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
</div>
```

Comment: Good solution! Also note, that absence of line-breaks or spaces in source html between text and link is mandatory.

Comment: @djxak "absence of spaces mandatory" - what do you mean? There *has* to be a space between the text and a/the link, otherwise it would be displayed as one word.

Comment: I mean absense of normal spaces or line breaks in **source html code**. It is common practice to format html code as you want. Place each element on different line for example or use indentation. In this case it is not allowed to place line break between `&nbsp;` and `<a href="">...</a>`.

Comment: @djxak ah, okay, now I understand. Yes, that's important, otherwise there would be a regular (possibly "breaking") space which works against that concept.

Comment: Great solution, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only "good" solution that I see is kind of workaround using zero-width spaces (`&#8203;`), inserted into link's text (not the url, just text) after each several characters (ideally one) using javascript or server-side.

```css
.parent {
  display : inline; 
}
.first {
  display: inline;
}
.second {
  display: inline;
  max-width: fill-available;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first">
    Hello
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <a href="#">Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man&#8203;Man</a>
  </div>
</div>`
```

Not really a good solution, but I can't imagine anything better.

#### Edit:

Another solution is to add `white-space: nowrap;` style to the `.first` element (or use `&nbsp;`) and **remove any whitespaces and linebreaks between `.first` and `.second` elements** in source html.

```css
.parent{
  display : inline;
}
.first{
  display : inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.second{
  display : inline;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first">Hello </div><div class="second"><a href="#">ManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManManMan</a>
  </div>
</div>
```